# How can one show that $y(\vartheta,t) \neq y_t(\vartheta)$ except at $\vartheta = \vartheta_0$ with the integral expressions given?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

I have the following functions:
\begin{align*}
y_t(\vartheta)&=y_0 \exp \left( \int_0^t a(\vartheta,s)ds   \right) \\
\dot{y}(\vartheta_0,t)&= \int_0^t e^{\int_s^t a(\vartheta_0,r)-D(\vartheta_0,r)f(\vartheta_0,r)dr}\left[\dot{a}(\vartheta_0,s)-D(\vartheta_0,s)\dot{f}(\vartheta_0,s)\right]y_s(\vartheta_0)ds
\end{align*}
The dot marks differentiation wrt $\vartheta$. 
The author of the paper that I currently read (1) claims that $y(\vartheta,t)\neq y_t(\vartheta)$ except at point $\vartheta_0$ and $\dot{y}(\vartheta_0,t) \neq \dot{y}_t(\vartheta_0)$. The latter is clear by differentiating the function $y_t(\vartheta_0)$. Intuitively, the first claim is also clear, but how can I show this claim? One could, of course, try to integrate the function $\dot{y}(\vartheta_0,t)$, but it involves several other very complicated functions, so, in my opinion, there must be an easier way to deduce the claim that $y(\vartheta,t)\neq y_t(\vartheta)$ except at point $\vartheta_0$. One can observe that the derivative $\dot{y}(\vartheta_0,t)$ is integral $\int_0^t$ of some function times the function $y$ itself.

Do you have ideas how to conclude?

(1): https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-15/issue-1/On-parameter-estimation-of-the-hidden-Gaussian-process-in-perturbed/10.1214/20-EJS1788.full